# Python Как сделать int итерабельным?

Tags: python

Суть самой проблемы заключается в том, что я получил изначально *int* в виде *str*, а после перевёл в число. Перевод был выполнен успешно, но когда это число я применяю в цикле *for*, выдаёт ошибку:

**TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable**

Comment: А какого эффекта вы хотите добиться перебором числа ? оно же одно, что именно в нем перебирать

Comment: Никак, не нужно делать число int итерабельным. Если вам нужно посчитать от 0 до вашего числа, воспользуйтесь range. Вообще, опишите что конкретно вы хотите получить в итоге (какую задачу вы пытаетесь решить), чтобы нам не нужно было догадываться.

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, код и опишите что вы делаете.

Comment: А что по строке не судьба итерироваться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть несколько способов проитерироваться по числу

1. Перевести в итерабельный тип, например, строку или список
2. Целочисленно делить на 10 и брать остаток:

   ```py
   n = 123
   while (n != 0):
       print(n % 10)
       n //= 10
   ```