# перебрать число по символьно

Tags: c++

как перебрать число, например 157, по символьно. Тоесть, чтобы мы могли делать некие действия с числом 1, с 5, и с 7.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Дубликат вопроса:: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1309499/451355

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Python Как сделать int итерабельным?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1309499/python-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-int-%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc)

Answer (score 1):

Порядок важен или нет?

```
while(n)
{
    int digit = n%10; 
    // Делать что-то с digit
    n /= 10;
}
```

Или

```
string s = to_string(n);
for(char digit_char: s) // Делать что-то с digit_char
```

Есть и другие варианты...

Answer (score 1):

чтобы разобрать число на цифры вам необходим такой алгоритм:

```
пока число не равно 0:
    цифра = число делить по модулю на 10
    число = число делить на 10
```

так вы выделите все цифры числа

Пример

```
2021:

2021 % 10 = 1
2021 / 10 = 202

202 % 10 = 2
202 / 10 = 20

20 % 10 = 0
20 / 10 = 2

2 % 10 = 2
2 / 10 = 0

цикл закончен
```